# Two color section full width with "restrcited" container width

Tags: css

The idea is that certaint section of the page have two color by column:
`[ Column left color red ] [ Column right color green ]`
So basically the html right now looks like this.

```
<section id="foo">
 <div class="wrapper-content">
  <div class="col-sm-5 bg-red">Some content</div>
  <div class="col-sm-7 bg-green">Some Other Content</div>
 </div>
</section>
```

That gives me how I need it to look, full width 2 columns with different colours, the problem is the container.
First image is what I need
Second image is what I'm getting

[image: Main Idea]

[image: What I\'m getting]

Following code is not working at all....

```
<section id="foo">
 <div class="wrapper-content">
  <div class="col-sm-5 bg-red same-height"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-7 bg-green same-height"></div>
  <div class="container absolute">          
   <div class="col-sm-5">Some content</div>
   <div class="col-sm-7">Some Other Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Colour on the left hast to go all the way left, the colour on the right all the way right, bu the content has to stay center and between the two columns.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This may work. You have to put divs of the same background color behind your foreground divs, absolutely positioned.

The container doesn't restrict the size at small widths, so you may have to expand the snippet to full page to see the results (the black borders are there to show the boundaries of your content areas)

```css
.header {
  background-color: beige;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.main-content {
  position: relative;
}

.left-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.right-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
}

.left-fg {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.right-fg {
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 30px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="header">Header</div>

<div class="main-content">
  <div class="left-bg"></div>
  <div class="right-bg"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="left-fg col-xs-5">Hello</div>
      <div class="right-fg col-xs-7">Goodbye</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a `container` class to your content section too.

Or put your content section into the header wrapper div.

Example: If your header div is wrapped with a class `<div class="container">...</div>`, also wrap the content div with this class too.

#### Sample 1: if you want different sections for both header and content

```
<div class="container">
    <div>Header</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div>Your content section</div>
</div>
```

#### Sample 2: if you dont need header and content sections to be separated

```
<div class="container">
    <div>Header</div>
    <div>Your content section</div>
</div>
```